# How can I get JUST a unique list of files that changed on remote server since my last pull with Git

Tags: git

We are trying to figure out whether it makes sense to move to git from our previous version control system.
One issue that we're struggling with is how to figure out succintly what files have been changed by someone else over all commits since the last pull. **In particular, if the same file has been changed in multiple commits, we just want to see that file once in the list.**
From what I have read, it seems I have to actually pull the remote repository before I can check but even then, there doesn't seem to be a (simple?) way to just get a list of all filenames that have changed.
Our understanding of git is not very deep yet, but the concern with doing a fetch is that some very large files (images, aiff and so forth) may have been pushed and nobody wants to have to fetch everything just to find out what has changed?
I've read a few of the other Q/As in stackoverflow but although I've seen questions that seem similar, I haven't seen any answers that seem viable.
We have been trying out several GUI tools to make life easier (Tower and SmartGit) but neither of them seems to be able to do this.

Comment: What access do you have to the central repository? You may be able to run `diff` on the remote repository before you fetch. For optimal use git relies on fetch being fast. There may be a better solution than storing large binary resources in your source code repository.

Comment: I have full access to the central repository --- we just created a repo on a linux server to which we all have direct access via ssh. What would you be diffing on the central repository? The idea would be to see what has changed remotely vs what is on each user's system. However, I think you may be right that there's no decent way to do this without fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do show which files have changed between current and previous master:

```
git fetch
git diff --stat master origin/master
```

The first command retrieves the latest updates without changing your tree. The second one prints a list of changed files (along with insertion/deletion stats)—across all commits that would have been pulled if you had typed `git pull`. Afterwards, you can run `git merge origin/master` to merge your changes with the upstream ones. (This is equivalent to a `git pull`, except that pull can get *new* changes from the server if any have been pushed in the meantime.)

Unfortunately, git doesn't make it obvious how to diff *without* pulling the updates locally.

Comment: But @David wants to avoid fetching before know the results of the diff.

Comment: @CharlesBailey I suspect the OP is more worried about pulling in upstream changes before having had a chance to review them. Workflow based on `git fetch`, often neglected in beginner's courses, avoids this problem.

Comment: He specifically states that he is concerned with the fetch and the size of the fetch.

Comment: That's correct. I understand the difference between fetch and pull. I wanted to be able to find out what had changed remotely without having to transfer stuff across the wire. It may be that git doesn't support this concept.

Comment: @David AFAIK stock git doesn't support remote diffing. Client-server VCSs like svn implement it because they consult the server for operations such as diff anyway. In contrast, `git` is designed for local operation, with only intermittent peer-to-peer synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

With direct access via ssh to the repository you can run something like this from a local clone.

```
ssh githost "git --git-dir=/data/repo.git diff --name-only\
             $(git rev-parse origin/master) master"
```

You probably want to put this in a script or alias. Note the the `$(git rev-parse origin/master)` runs locally in the clone to retrieve the id of the clone's remote tracking branch.

Comment: This gives me meaningful errors such as 

error: Could not access 'add7b64b5545e06a6cbc2445474e1cb5c2453189'

Comment: @David: What happens if you just do something like `ssh githost "git --git-dir=/data/repo.git show`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git log --stat
```

That should print out a detailed log of the currently checked out repository.

Not sure git will do what you want without checking out locally first.

Comment: `git log --stat` fails to address the requirement (specified in bold typeface) to only list once files changed in multiple commits.

Comment: More importantly, this shows the stuff I have committed, it does not show what files have changed in the remote repository since the last time I did a pull.